# SP 2013 AD import leaves out some user accounts

Tags: ad

For some reason doung an AD import leaves some user accounts 'missing.
The account I'm  using certainly has "Replicating Diredtory Changes Permissions" but still a no go.
Odd thing is if someone from the aforementioned "missing accounts" sends me an email , they show up on the AD list after a full sync.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: how often you run the AD improt job?

Comment: Lately just on demand. Keep trying until I can see the missin knes show up but they havent.